# python: pandas.dataframe.values not chaning

Tags: python, pandas

I am finding strange value assignment restriction in pandas dataframe. Here's a simple illustration

```
   from __future__ import print_function
   from pandas import DataFrame 
   import numpy as np

   data=DataFrame({'one':[1,2],'two':[3.0,4]})
   data.values[1,1]=data.values[1,1]*6 # these are type<numpyfloat64>
   print(data.values[1,1])
   #still returns 4.0 instead of expected 24.0
```

I'd appreciate an explanation as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access the `values` attribute of an `NDFrame` object, you receive an array that is *homogeneous* in its type. That is, `values` returns an array of a *single* `dtype` that is the largest precision among the `dtype`s of the columns in your `DataFrame`. In your case, `one` is an `int64` `dtype` while, `two` is `float64`. When you call `values`, ultimately a `concatenate` style operation happens, and those always return a copy, which is why you can't assign to it and see the side effect in the data.

Answer (score 0):

`data.values` is a separate array, not a reference to the original object. It just reads data from `data`. Yes, it does not change the original values because it does not represent them, it is basically their copy.

To change the values directly, use [loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy):

```
data.loc[1, 'one'] *= 6
```

Comment: `data['one'][1] *= 6` may or may not always work. See [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)  A safer way is `data.ix[1,'one']*=6`

Comment: @Happy001 Oh, wow, didn't know this. Will edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation of Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#attributes-and-the-raw-ndarray-s)

> The values attribute itself, unlike the axis labels, cannot be assigned to.

Thus this is the expected behavior. The following code is a way to change the value.

```
data.two[1] = data.two[1] * 6
```